# Is there a way to use the melt function in Python for multiple columns?

Tags: python, pandas, melt

I have a table in a cross-tab format, example below:

```html
State   Item #  x1  x2  x3  y1  y2  y3  z1  z2  z3
CA      1       6   4   3   7   5   3       11      5       1
CA      2       7   3   1   15  10  5       4       2       1
FL      3       3   2   1   5   3   2       13      7       2
FL      4       9   4   2   16  14  12      14      5       4
```

I am trying to use the melt function to put the data in the following format:

```html
State   Item #  x   xvalue  y   yvalue  z   zvalue
CA      1       x1    6     y1    7     z1    11
CA      1       x2    4     y2    5     z2    5
CA      1       x3    3     y3    3     z3    1
CA      2       x1    7     y1    15    z1    4
CA      2       x2    3     y2    10    z2    2
CA      2       x3    1     y3    5     z3    1
```

I know how to use the melt function to do it for just one of the values, say x. But I don't know how to do it with y and z too. See my code below for doing it for just x. Is there a way I can adjust this to do it for y and z also? Or should I try having separate melt functions for x, y, and z, and then somehow combine them?

```html
df_m = pd.melt(df, id_vars=['State', 'Item #'],
           value_vars=['x1','x2','x3'],
           var_name='x', value_name='xvalue')
```

Comment: I think you may need to do multiple melts.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think so, but you could use two line solution:

```
values = [['x1','x2','x3'], ['y1', 'y2', 'y3'], ['z1', 'z2', 'z3']]

df_m = pd.concat([pd.melt(df, id_vars=['State', 'Item_#'], value_vars=val, var_name='var', value_name='value') for val in values])
```

The `pd.concat` function is a powerful (i.e. fast) way to stack DataFrames vertically.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a version that does not use `melt` but works for any number of xyz 'groups'.

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO('''
    State   ItemN  x1  x2  x3  y1  y2  y3  z1  z2  z3
CA      1       6   4   3   7   5   3       11      5       1
CA      2       7   3   1   15  10  5       4       2       1
FL      3       3   2   1   5   3   2       13      7       2
FL      4       9   4   2   16  14  12      14      5       4'''),
sep=r' +')

# prepare index
df = df.set_index(list(df.columns[:2]))
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([(c[0], c) for c in df.columns])

#              x         y           z      
#             x1 x2 x3  y1  y2  y3  z1 z2 z3
# State ItemN                               
# CA    1      6  4  3   7   5   3  11  5  1
#       2      7  3  1  15  10   5   4  2  1
# FL    3      3  2  1   5   3   2  13  7  2
#       4      9  4  2  16  14  12  14  5  4


# stack and concat each 'group'
df2 = pd.concat((
    df[c].stack().reset_index(-1)
    for c in df.columns.levels[0]),
    axis=1)

# rename the columns
new_cols = [None for _ in range(df2.shape[1])]
new_cols[::2]  = [c for c in df.columns.levels[0]]
new_cols[1::2] = [c + 'value' for c in df.columns.levels[0]]

df2.columns = new_cols

#               x  xvalue   y  yvalue   z  zvalue
# State ItemN                                    
# CA    1      x1       6  y1       7  z1      11
#       1      x2       4  y2       5  z2       5
#       1      x3       3  y3       3  z3       1
#       2      x1       7  y1      15  z1       4
#       2      x2       3  y2      10  z2       2
#       2      x3       1  y3       5  z3       1
# FL    3      x1       3  y1       5  z1      13
#       3      x2       2  y2       3  z2       7
#       3      x3       1  y3       2  z3       2
#       4      x1       9  y1      16  z1      14
#       4      x2       4  y2      14  z2       5
#       4      x3       2  y3      12  z3       4
```

Answer (score 0):

What about [`pd.wide_to_long`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.wide_to_long.html#pandas-wide-to-long)?

```
# Make dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'State' : ['CA']*2 + ['FL']*2,
                   'Item' : [1, 2, 3, 4],
                   'x1' : [6, 7, 3, 9],
                   'x2' : [4, 3, 2, 4],
                   'x3' : [3, 1, 1, 2],
                   'y1' : [7, 15, 5, 16],
                   'y2' : [5, 10, 3, 14],
                   'y3' : [3, 5, 2, 12],
                   'z1' : [11, 4, 13, 14],
                   'z2' : [5, 2, 7, 5],
                   'z3' : [1, 1, 2, 4]})

# Make final dataframe using pd.wide_to_long
final = pd.wide_to_long(df,
                        stubnames = ['x', 'y', 'z'],
                        i = ['State',
                             'Item'],
                        j = 'number').reset_index()

# Show final dataframe
final
```

[image: wide_to_long]

I know the dataframe returned doesn't look exactly like the one you requested but it could still work. In fact, it now combines your x, y, z, xvalue, yvalue, and zvalue columns into x, y, z, and a 'number' column for referring to the first, second, and third values.

Answer (score 0):

One option is with [pivot_longer](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.pivot.pivot_longer) from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/), using a list of regular expressions, taking advantage of the ordering (`x1,y1,z1`, `x2,y2,z2`, ...):

```py
# currently in dev
# pip install git+https://github.com/pyjanitor-devs/pyjanitor.git
import pandas as pd
import janitor

names_to = ['x', 'y', 'z']
values_to = ['xvalue', 'yvalue', 'zvalue']

df.pivot_longer(
    index = ['State', 'Item'], 
    names_to = names_to, 
    values_to = values_to, 
    names_pattern = names_to, 
    sort_by_appearance = True)

   State  Item   x  xvalue   y  yvalue   z  zvalue
0     CA     1  x1       6  y1       7  z1      11
1     CA     1  x2       4  y2       5  z2       5
2     CA     1  x3       3  y3       3  z3       1
3     CA     2  x1       7  y1      15  z1       4
4     CA     2  x2       3  y2      10  z2       2
5     CA     2  x3       1  y3       5  z3       1
6     FL     3  x1       3  y1       5  z1      13
7     FL     3  x2       2  y2       3  z2       7
8     FL     3  x3       1  y3       2  z3       2
9     FL     4  x1       9  y1      16  z1      14
10    FL     4  x2       4  y2      14  z2       5
11    FL     4  x3       2  y3      12  z3       4
```